# How can create a loop to count an specific "Child" in a list of "Children"?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jtree, jdom-2

Consider the following XML file:

```
<project>
    <props>
        <prop name="currency" value="USD" />
        <prop name="user-type" value="admin" />
    </props>

    <plans>
        <plan name="-" showFirst="false" showSecond="false">
            <props>
                <prop name="moneyback" value="true" />
                <prop name="capacity" value="5" />
            </props>
            <section id="setup"/>
            <section id="hardware" defaultChoice="machines">
                <parts level="1">
                    <part choice="machine_001" name="DAP010" />
                    <part choice="machine_002" name="DAP011" />
                </parts>
            </section>
            <section id="software" />     
            <queues>
                <queue type="q2" minPlan="CC_Q" />
            </queues>
        </plan>


        <plan name="A" showFirst="true" showSecond="true">
            <users>
                <user planName="classic" cost="$20.00" />
                <user planName="lite" cost="$10.00" />
            </users>
        </plan>

        <plan name="B" showFirst="true" showSecond="false">
            <props>
                <prop name="moneyback" value="false" />
                <prop name="capacity" value="2" />
            </props>
            <section id="setup"/>
            <section id="software" />     
            <queues>
                <queue type="q2" minPlan="CC_Q" />
            </queues>
        </plan>

    </plans>
</project>
```

Using the "JDOM2",

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  JFileChooser ServiceOfferFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
  ServiceOfferFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
  ServiceOfferFileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
  FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.xml", "xml");
  ServiceOfferFileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);

  int resultChangeServiceOfferFileChooser = ServiceOfferFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

  if (resultChangeServiceOfferFileChooser == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File selectedServiceOfferFile = ServiceOfferFileChooser.getSelectedFile();

    SAXBuilder soRead = new SAXBuilder();

    Document ReadSO;
    try {
      ReadSO = soRead.build(new File(selectedServiceOfferFile.getPath()));

      JTree loadedTree = new JTree();
      loadedTree.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(
        new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Service Offer") {

          private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

          {
            add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Service Offer Properties"));

            List<Element> soPlans = ReadSO.getRootElement().getChild("plans").getChildren();
            for(int i=0;i<soPlans.size();i++){
              Element soPlan = soPlans.get(i);
              DefaultMutableTreeNode node_soPlan = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Plan: "+soPlan.getAttributeValue("name"));
                add(node_soPlan);

                List<Element> plansProps = soPlans.get(i).getChildren();
                for (int ii=0;ii<=plansProps.size()-1;ii++){
                  Element plansProp = plansProps.get(ii);
                  node_soPlan.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(plansProp));
                }
            }

          }
        }
      ));
      newTree.setVisible(false);
      westNorthPanel.add(loadedTree);
```

---

[This is how my JTree looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p65Y.png)

---

Regarding that I need each of the Children `"props"`, `"section"`, `"queues"`, and `"user"` has their own label as I define, So I have to count each of these Child Element in their parent element Plan.

I created a loop which counts number of the Child `"Plan"` in its parent `"Plans"`. How?

```java
List<Element> soPlans = ReadSO.getRootElement().getChild("plans").getChildren();
            for(int i=0;i<soPlans.size();i++){
              Element soPlan = soPlans.get(i);
```

---

Please note that the `"List<Element>"` implies a "list" which is satisfied by ensemble of "children".

Now the issue and my question is that in the second loop I want that the codes visits all `"Plans"` and when it find a `"props"` creates JTree node with desired text.

The problem is that if I use the method [`.getChild("props")`] after the method "`.getChildren()`", compiler correctly complains that I need to change "`List<Element>`" into "`Elemen`"; and by doing so, the method "`.size()`" is not defined for the "`PlansProps`"

```java
List<Element> plansProps = soPlans.get(i).getChildren();
                    for (int ii=0;ii<=plansProps.size()-1;ii++){
                      Element plansProp = plansProps.get(ii);
                      node_soPlan.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(plansProp));
                    }
```

---

How can I use a "for (int)" loop to count a certain "Element" and not a "List of Elements"

Comment: We note the scenario is to build a loop which its counter is based on the number of a specific ".child()" which returns a "String" where the method [.getsize(index)] is not defined. And not based on ".children()" which returns a "List"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve my goal through implementing another method [`.getQualifiedName()`] for the Element declared inside the second loop where we can use the method [`.getSize()`] for the loop counter:

```java
SAXBuilder soRead = new SAXBuilder();

  Document ReadSO;
  try {
    ReadSO = soRead.build(new File(selectedServiceOfferFile.getPath()));

    JTree loadedTree = new JTree();
    loadedTree.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(
      new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Service Offer") {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        {
          add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Service Offer Properties"));

          List<Element> soPlans = ReadSO.getRootElement().getChild("plans").getChildren();
          for(int i=0;i<soPlans.size();i++){
            Element soPlan = soPlans.get(i);
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node_soPlan = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Plan: "+soPlan.getAttributeValue("name"));
              add(node_soPlan);

          **List<Element> plansProps = soPlans.get(i).getChildren();**
          for (int ii=0;ii<=plansProps.size()-1;ii++){
            Element plansProp = plansProps.get(ii);
            **if (plansProp.getQualifiedName()** == "props"){
              node_soPlan.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Plan Properties"));
            }
            else if (plansProp.getQualifiedName() == "section"){
              //System.out.println(plansProp.getAttributeValue("id"));
              node_soPlan.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Section: "+plansProp.getAttributeValue("id")));
            }
            else if (plansProp.getQualifiedName() == "queues"){
              node_soPlan.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Queue Licences: "));
            }
            else if (plansProp.getQualifiedName() == "users"){
              node_soPlan.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Users: "));
            }
            else {
              node_soPlan.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(plansProp));
            }

            System.out.println(plansProp.getAttributeValue("id"));
          }

      }


    }
  }
```

---

[**And now this is how does it look like:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpbmz.png)